# Cannot Figure Out How to Remove String cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn From Small Clojure Function

Tags: clojure

I have a small clojure function:

```
(defn split-legal-ref
  "Highly specific function that expects one AssessPro map and a map key,
   from which book and page will be extracted."
  [assess-pro-acct extract-key]
  (let [[book page] (cstr/split (extract-key assess-pro-acct) #"-")]
    (list (cstr/trim book) (cstr/trim page))))
```

Given this: `(extract-key assess-pro-acct) #"-")`, the `extract-key`'s value is `:legal_ref`. So, it is fetching a single value like `927-48` out of a map and splitting the value using '-'. I just need to catch when there isn't one of those nice values. That is where the split returns nil.

So, I am stuck having tried to replace the original function with the following.

```
(def missing-book 888)
(def missing-page 999)
.
.
.
(defn split-legal-ref
  "Highly specific function that expects one AssessPro map and a map key,
   from which book and page will be extracted."
  [assess-pro-acct extract-key]
    (let [[book page] (cstr/split (extract-key assess-pro-acct) #"-")]
     (let [[trimBook trimPage] ((if book (cstr/trim book) (missing-book))
                                        (if page (cstr/trim page)  (missing-page)))]
        (list (trimBook) (trimPage)))))
```

The problem is I keep getting the dreaded

`String cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn From Small Clojure Function`

error. How can I restructure this function to avoid the error?

***Post Answers Edit:***

Thank you for the answers:

I reworked the function to test for a "-" in a string. If it's not there, I use a dummy "888-99" as a value when none is there.

```
(def missing-book-page "888-99")
.
.
.

(defn split-legal-ref
  "Highly specific function that expects one AssessPro map and a map key,
   from which book and page will be extracted."
    [assess-pro-acct extract-key]
    (let [[book page] 
            (if (.contains "-" (extract-key assess-pro-acct))
            (cstr/split (extract-key assess-pro-acct) #"-")
            (cstr/split  missing-book-page #"-"))]
        (list (cstr/trim book) (cstr/trim page))))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have an extra set of parentheses around the expression beginning with `((if book ...`. The `if` expression returns a string, and then since that string is in the first position of a list with the outer of those 2 parentheses, Clojure tries to invoke the string as a function.

Parentheses are very, very significant in Clojure.  Unlike arithmetic expressions in languages like Fortran, C, C++, Java, Python, etc., where adding an extra set of parentheses around a subexpression is redundant, and maybe bad style, but harmless, it changes the meaning of Clojure expressions.

Comment: I wouldn't call this an "extra set" of parentheses, although usually that's what this error means. Rather, parentheses were used when square brackets should have been used instead, to produce a two-element vector. Once this issue is resolved, more sets of extra parentheses will give @octopusgrabbus issues with integers being called as functions: `(missing-book)` should be `missing-book`.

Comment: Basically, I have not used Clojure in so long, that I made the function (added to answer) more readable (at least to me), and substituted a dummy value "888-99" if the mapped value returned just a blank string. Thank you for answering this.

Answer (score 1):

Can you add more information, like the function names and sample data?  Also include more of the error message.

Somewhere in your code you are attempting to use a string as if it were a function.  For example:

```
("hello" 3)  ; should be (inc 3) or something.  This is line #6
```

This generates the following error

```
ERROR in (dotest-line-5) (core.clj:6)
Uncaught exception, not in assertion.
expected: nil
  actual: java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class clojure.lang.IFn (java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; clojure.lang.IFn is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
 at tst.demo.core$fn__18295.invokeStatic (core.clj:6)
<snip>
```

Note the last line of the error above refers to `core.clj:6` which matches the namespace `tst.demo.core` and line number `6` where `(hello 3)` is found in the source code.